# Реализовать собственный IFilter для полнотекстового поиска

Tags: c++, delphi, sql-server, com, полнотекстовый-поиск

Необходимо реализовать свой фильтр для полнотекстового поиска. Есть файл со своим расширением `.sc`, он содержит `xml` и в одном из тегов `.doc` файл в бинарном представлении. Нужно, чтобы полнотекстовый поиск (фильтр наследуемый от IFilter) искал по словам во вложенном документе .doc.

Выяснил, что полнотекстовый поиск MS-SQL использует те же фильтры, что и Windows Desktop Search. Нашел пример фильтра на с++ [тут](https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/tree/master/winui/WindowsSearch/IFilterSample), но он просто использует уже готовый фильтр Adobe, а не регистрирует свой как [RarFilter](http://www.ifiltershop.com/rar-ifilter.html). Так же нашел данный пример на c# [тут](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13391/Using-IFilter-in-C), его регистрирую через regasm, добавляю ключи в реестр из [описания](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/lwef/-search-2x-wds-ifilteraddins), но поиск результаты не выдает, утилита filtdump выбрасывает код ошибки 0x80048014. Больше примеров по фильтрам я не нашел, есть готовые [тут](http://www.ifiltershop.com/rar-ifilter.html), они регистрируются без проблем.

Как реализовать свой фильтр?

Comment: _"пример на c# ... регистрирую через regasm"_ - а там нечего регистрировать, там нет реализации IFilter, только обёртка для вызова IFilter-ов из c# кода. Вообще _In Windows 7 and later, filters written in managed code are explicitly blocked. Filters MUST be written in native code_ ([отсюда](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb266451)), т.е. на c# написать фильтр не получится (разве что попробовать написать нативную либу на c++, которая бы вызывала код из c# библиотеки, но в данном случае скорее всего целесообразнее будет писать сразу на с++).

Comment: @i-one в с++ у меня уровень не очень, но подошел бы пример регистрации на c++ или можно delphi,

Comment: Я на с++ и delphi сто лет ничего не писал, а для com - двести (когда-то давно делал shell extension-ы для win98). Надеюсь, что плюсовики или дельфисты откликнутся (добавил метки с++ и delphi к вопросу). В общих чертах примерно понятно как это реализовать - фильтр должен по входящему потоку пройти xmlreader-ом до узла с .doc-файлом, далее нужно вызвать IFilter зарегистрированный для .doc, передать ему поток, в который подавать декодированный .doc, и далее свой фильтр по идее должен просто быть обёрткой для office-IFilter, прокидывая ему вызовы.

Comment: @i-one  ну вроде начало получаться, я дошел до момента, когда определил нужный тег и вытащил данные для .doc. Теперь нужно прикрутить фильтр для парсинга .doc

Comment: В том примере на c#, кстати, есть вся эта логика (как вызвать фильтр для .doc расширения), только там делается обработка файла (IPersistFile), а по-хорошему надо обработку потока делать (IPersistStream).

Comment: вот бы на с++ бы эту логику перевести сейчас )))